# SQL Server network perfomance over linked server

Tags: sql-server, performance, networking, linked-server

Here's a tricky question: Server A (SQL Server 2016) pulls data form server B (SQL Server 2014 SP1) and C (SQL Server 2014 SP1) over linked server.

Linked servers are configured using the same user, that has the same permissions on B and C servers.

B and C servers has the same database with the same table (4M rows).

I use simple statements on server A:

```
select * 
into .. 
from [Linked server table]
```

When I run the queries, I get different network performance:

- A server pulls data from server B at 40mbps
- A server pulls data from server C at 20mbps.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: This question is subjective. You'll need to do some investigation.

Comment: Are servers in the same room? Did you do pinging? Any network troubleshooting?

Comment: Server A is a VM on my PC.
Servers B and C are in the cloud in the same Vendor, but different VMs.
Ping is the same.
Also I tried to test over SSIS - then I get the same speed.

Comment: Vendor says there are no network problems.